# Handling Multiple Handlers with Python Watchdog

Tags: python, watchdog, python-watchdog

I am a first time user of watchdog. I wanted to know how can watchdog handle multiple handlers. Would it be something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                        datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    path = sys.argv[1] if len(sys.argv) > 1 else '.'
    event_handler_1 = LoggingEventHandler()
    **event_handler_2 = LoggingEventHandler()**
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler_1, path, recursive=True)
    **observer.schedule(event_handler_2, path, recursive=True)**
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Would appreciate help in this

Comment: I've only used the watchdog commandline, so I don't have the answer to your problem.  One thing I might try is creating a second observer and seeing if that works. . .

Comment: so, would it be something like start multiple observers, then stopping them during keyboard interrupt and calling a join on each observer?

Comment: Sure.  You could try it.  Based on the API, it looks like each will run in it's own thread and python will support multiple threads without any problem. . .

Comment: ok thank you. i will try that. can you help me with one more thing? I will be running my watchdog script as a background job using nohup. lets say i stop/remove the job, how can i ensure that the observers are stopped, i.e. what exception can i catch?

Comment: I don't know if any particular exception will be caught.  I'd expect `nohup` to kill the process by default unless you register a handler to catch it (e.g. via [`signal.signal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html#signal.signal))

Comment: ok, thank you very much for your help. i really appreciate it :)

Comment: is it working?
i am trying to add handler to a watch.
but only single handler is working.